# HP Pavilion dv6 screen goes black after Windows loads, but not in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, hp-pavilion, black-screen-of-death

When I boot the laptop normally, it goes through POST, and I can see the "Starting Windows" screen with the Windows logo.  However, right before I get to the Windows logon, the screen goes black. In safe mode the computer works fine; I also did a heavy virus removal.

The operating system is Windows 7 Home Premium.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Try to uninstall the graphic driver in safe mode and also any new software which you installed earlier. And tell us when you started get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your video settings are set to a resolution or refresh rate your monitor doesn't support.

Instead of going into Safe Mode, go into regular mode, but in low-resolution:

Hit F8, but instead of "Safe Mode", pick "Enable low-resolution video".  This will boot regularly, but with the video in "VGA" mode.

If that works, then hard-set your resolution to 1024x768 or something relatively low (but better than 640x480), that you know the monitor (etc) supports.

Reboot normally, if it works, then you can adjust your resolution to your desired setting(s).

Comment: This help me do some trouble shooting, it turns out the OS was just corrupted. A clean re install fixed it. Thank you though, it helped.